# Design pattern to check FMA in multiple places in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, feature-management

We are building a managed package, we are having 10 business modules which is built on lightning component.

Recently we got a requirement to render the certain modules based on the feature management parameters (FMA). 
As a user when you visit a LEX Tab we check if the feature is enabled or not. If enabled, we render the actual component else we show a banner screen where we explain the feature and provide a button the user to enable it.
Some of the components are exposed as LEX tabs (or) App builder, however those components is also used as child component as part of a business module.

Inorder to implement the FMA check on the Main component, we were exploring few options but not sure which would work well for us.

1) Main components extending a Basc component which checks for the FMA and calls the init method of child until then child view will be hidden

**FMABaseCheck.cmp**

```
<aura:component extensible="true">
    <aura:attribute name="featureName" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.checkFeatureIsEnabled}" />

    <c:banner feature="{!v.featureName}" aura:id="bannerview"/>
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**FMABaseCheckController.js**

```
{
    checkFeatureIsEnabled : function(cmp, event, helper) {
        //call server to check the feature
        action.setCallback(this, function(resp) {
            if (resp.getReturnValue()) {
                //hide banner component
                cmp.getConcreteComponent().initialize();
            }
        })
    }

}
```

**TaskView.cmp:**

```
<aura:component extends="c:FMABaseCheck">
    <aura:method name="initialize" action="{!c.init}" />
    <div>....</div>
</aura:component>
```

2) Develop a FMA checking functionality as a Service component and include it as wrapper of the actual component to be displayed.

**FMAChecker.cmp**

```
<aura:component controller="FMAChecker">
    <aura:attribute name="featureName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="isFeatureEnabled" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:attribute name="featureComponent" type="Aura.Component[]" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.checkFeatureIsEnabled}" />

    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isFeatureEnabled}">
        {!v.featureComponent}
        <aura:set attribute="else">
                <c:banner feature="{!v.featureName}" aura:id="bannerview"/>
        </aura:set>
</aura:component>
```

**TaskViewer.cmp:**

```
<aura:component extends="c:FMABaseCheck">

    <c:FMAChecker feature="taskView">
        <aura:set attribute="featureComponent">
            <c:TaskView />
        </aura:set>
    <c:FMAChecker/>
</aura:component>
```

Not sure which of the above would work well for us considering lots of modules will be added in the future. We'll be interest to hear if there's any other better pattern to achieve what we are doing.